# How to redirect of all url to 1 url only using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-routing

Can any one help me to redirect of all url to 1 url only using .htaccess

For example, all the following URLs...

```
"http//josephm.webatu.com/index.php"
"http//josephm.webatu.com/login.php"
"http//josephm.webatu.com/games.php"
```

Should only show url `http://josephm.webatu.com`

to make it clear, all the following URLs...

```
"http//josephm.webatu.com/index.php"
"http//josephm.webatu.com/login.php"
"http//josephm.webatu.com/games.php"
```

will only hide

```
"index.php"
"login.php"
"games.php"
```

from browsers url address bar not goto http://josephm.webatu.com

Answer (score 0):

Using mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch ^/(index|login|games)\.php$ /
```

Add a `301`, `RedirectMatch 301`, if you want a permanent redirect.

Using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?(index|login|games)\.php$ / [L,R]
```

Add a `=301` to the `R` flag: `R=301` if you want a permanent redirect.

Comment: what i mean is it will only hide

"index.php"
"login.php"
"games.php"
from browsers url address bar not goto http://josephm.webatu.com